# My Chrome extensions keep disappearing?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, sync, google-chrome-extensions

Yesterday almost all of my useful Google Chrome Extensions disappeared. I went to chrome://extensions and there was a repair button below the disappeared ones, [like this](https://s31.postimg.org/e2re91jaj/capture2.png). I googled a lot and from what appeared to had solved the problem in some cases I went to Google Dashboard and click on Reset Sync button at the bottom of the page, then completely uninstalled Chrome and reinstalled it to see if there's any change. But after installing every extension from Store again today my extensions just disappeared **with clicking on them** or **closing Chrome compelely**. But if chrome is running in background (chrome Tray-Icon is visible), then extensions don't disappear. But that means if I shutdown, or restart extension gonna disappear.

I Also sync everything in advanced sync settings. Any suggestions?

Comment: You linked to the same screenshot twice

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question isn't clear and contains statements that are immaterial to the question (the author hating Google Chrome is a rant)

Comment: @Ramhound sorry I wasn't familiar with post formatting, policy

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me solved when I used an **Anti-Malware** like [Zemana](https://www.zemana.com/AntiMalware). Apparently there were some bugs In my system that were causing this problem. But, since Zemana found some adwares and I removed them from my hard drive and I also uninstalled Google Chrome and removed all of its leftovers from registry and hard drive and installed again, I'm not completely sure if the problem cause was some chrome bug, or it was the adwares.